# EmberJS Model relationship not updating

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Let's say I have a company that contains n employees. From my Ember application I add a new employee using a POST to the server. Assuming everything went okay, I know want my `company.employee` list to update in the console. However, when I `findRecord` my `company`, my list still only contains n employees (rather than n+1). I've tried using `route.store.findRecord('company', 'companyX', { reload: true, include: 'employees' })`.

Can some please explain why my employee list remains stale ?

Because this needs to happen on the fly I'm having trouble debugging -- awaiting a query to the store is not possible mid-debug. But I have managed to run some commands in the console after adding the employee to confirm my problem:

```
company = route.store.findRecord('company', 'companyX', { reload: true, include: 'employees' };
employees = route.store.query('employee', { company : 'companyX' });
company.employees.length == employees.length; // false!
company.employees.reload();
company.employees.length == employees.length; // true!
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To clarify, you first called your POST update to the server, waited for it to complete successfully, then refetched the data from your server, and the network response from the server contained n+1 records, but Ember Data showed n records?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. A query for the list of employees returns n+1. And to be clear, during the route transitions, a company.employees.reload.then(log(company.employees).length()) still returns n, but a query of the employees list at the same moment, returns n+1 employees.

Comment: So normally, findRecord returns what peekRecord returns and background reloads the data. However, in this case you are calling { reload: true }. This should wait for a server call to return. But since you aren't awaiting it, I think the company variable is likely still holding the previously loaded object?